# Auth is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying this code. I am already save user name and Hash::make('123') in database.
**it's my controller**

```
    class EntriesController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $username = 'saqib';
        $password = '123';
        $hashPassword = Hash::make($password);

        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $hashPassword), true))
        {
            echo "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong";
            $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
            print_r(end($queries));
        }
    }
}
```

**and it's routes:**

```
Route::get('/', 'EntriesController@getIndex');
```

Comment: Array ( [query] => select * from `users` where `username` = ? limit 1 [bindings] => Array ( [0] => saqib ) [time] => 1 )

Comment: What does your `users` table look like? Does it have a `username` column? `user_name` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password not in hashed.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password), true))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Auth::attempt() you don't need to hash the password. Instead just do

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password), true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't hash password. Please find your below code:-

```
class EntriesController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $username = 'saqib';
        $password = '123';
        $hashPassword = Hash::make($password);

        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password), true))
        {
            echo "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong";
            $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
            print_r(end($queries));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Please check you database table "password" field its should allow 64 characters to store into it.(Hash password contains 64 characters)